# Script fields in hibernate elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I'm using hibernate-search-elasticsearch 5.8.2.Final and I can't figure out how to get script fields:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-request-script-fields.html

Is there any way to accomplish this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Hibernate Search 5.8.

In Hibernate Search 5.10 you could get [direct access to the REST client](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#elasticsearch-client-access), send a REST request to Elasticsearch and get the result as a JSON string that you would have to parse yourself, but it is very low-level and you would not benefit from the Hibernate Search search APIs at all (no query DSL, no managed entity loading, no direct translation entity type => index name, ...).

If you want better support for this feature, don't hesitate to open a ticket on [our JIRA](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HSEARCH/issues), describing in details what you are trying to achieve and how you would have expected to be able to do that. We are currently working on Search 6.0 which brings a lot of improvements, in particular when it comes to using native features of Elasticsearch, so it just might be something we could slip into our backlog.

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that, while you cannot use server-side scripts, you can still get the full source from your documents, and do some parsing in your application to achieve a similar result. This will work even in Search 5.8:

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEm = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
FullTextQuery query = fullTextEm.createFullTextQuery(
                    qb.keyword()
                    .onField( "tags" )
                    .matching( "round-based" )
                    .createQuery(),
                    VideoGame.class
            )
            .setProjection( ElasticsearchProjectionConstants.SCORE, ElasticsearchProjectionConstants.SOURCE );

Object[] projections = (Object[]) query.getSingleResult();
for (Object projection : projections) {
   float score = (float) projection[0];
   String source = (String) projection[1];
}
```

See [this section of the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.8/reference/en-US/html_single/#_projections).

Comment: Yes, I know about the projections and I'm using them, but here I need some dynamically evaluated fields(script fields), so it seems I can't do it with this version. :(

Comment: @HristoAngelov Out of curiosity, what features do you use in the scripts fields that could not be reproduced on the client side by parsing the document source and running it through some Java code?

Comment: Of course I can. I just wanted to use the processing time of the elasticsearch cluster, not the application server.

Comment: Right, that's clearly suboptimal. Thanks for the feedback.